# scm plugin with git

Tags: java, git, maven

When using scm maven plugin to checkout a project on a git repo, is this plugin using native git client altogether with the associated credentials ?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <configuration>
              <checkoutDirectory>...</checkoutDirectory>
              <connectionUrl>scm:git:...</connectionUrl>
              <scmVersion>...</scmVersion>
              <scmVersionType>...</scmVersionType>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>checkout</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>clean</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Why checking out with Maven? Use CI solution like Jenkins etc....